# Variable value doesn't change after returning it from a method

Tags: c#

I am a novice programmer (5 days experience), I am making a simple tic tac toe code to learn more about C#.

My problem is the value of variable `Turn` doesn't change after returning a new value from the method `PlayerTurn`.

I guess the problem is from this static vs non static which is so confusing to me

MainClass

```
using gamemainbody;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MehdiTicTacToe
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GameMainBody GMB = new GameMainBody();
            int Turn = 0; // 1 if player turn else 0
            string[] TheBoard = new string[9];
            GMB.PlayerTurn(Turn);
            Console.WriteLine(Turn);
            GMB.Board(TheBoard);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Class 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gamemainbody
{
    class GameMainBody
    {
        private string[] theBoard;
        private int turn;
        public int Turn {
            get => turn;
            set => turn = value; }
        public string[] TheBoard {
            get => theBoard;
            set => theBoard = value; }

        public void Board(string[] TheBoard)
        {
            this.TheBoard = TheBoard;

            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");

            Console.WriteLine("  {0}    |  {1}  |  {2}", TheBoard[0], TheBoard[1], TheBoard[2]);

            Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");

            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");

            Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", TheBoard[3], TheBoard[4], TheBoard[5]);

            Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");

            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");

            Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", TheBoard[6], TheBoard[7], TheBoard[8]);

            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
        }
        public int PlayerTurn(int Turn)
        {
            this.Turn = Turn;
            Console.WriteLine("Type X if you chose X");
            Console.WriteLine("Type O if you chose O");
            string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (UserInput == "X" || UserInput == "x")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PlayerTurn");
                Turn += 1;
                return Turn;
            }
            if (UserInput == "O" || UserInput == "o")
            {
                Turn = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("AI Turn");
                return Turn;
            }
            else
            {
                Turn -= 1;
                return Turn;
            }
        }
        public void GameCore(int Turn, string[] Board)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

After running this code, i printed the value of variable Turn and it's value was 0 still.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

The `Turn` is a [Value Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types), so you need this in the Main method to receive the changes:

```
Turn = GMB.PlayerTurn(Turn);
```

Comment: Your welcome, and the `ref` keyword could be your friend too, as Patrick mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify `Turn` explicitly to be passed as `ref`:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void ModifyInt(ref int x)  # ref keyword here
    {
        x = x * 2;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int value = 22;
        ModifyInt(ref value);         # ref keyword here

        Console.WriteLine( value );
    }
}
```

That way your [ValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) is explicitly passed by reference and altered: [ref (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

Output:

```
44
```

---

Using a return value would be my preferred way though :)

Comment: Thanks!, i didn't know about ref until now